# How to format the default tooltip to show dates

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When you hover over the bars you will see the raw epoch times.

How can I convert it to a readable date format, something like this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return  '<b>' + this.series.name +'</b><br/>' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', new Date(this.series.data[0].low)) + ', ' +
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%m-%d-%Y', new Date(this.series.data[0].high));
    }
},
```

Here is my JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/6qsvjark/157/.

Comment: That's a tough one, with the extra layer deep, I am not used to seeing the series with extra groupings the way you have it.  Sorry I couldnt be more help!

Comment: You need to refer to this.point.low / this.point.high and not use new Date();

Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/6qsvjark/162/

Comment: Ahhhh the new Date() was the issue.  Thanks so much!